# Why is an empty TCP segment at right edge of receive window not acceptable?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols

The TCPv4 specification (RFC 793) [classifies a received segment as unacceptable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#page-69) if it has zero length, a sequence number equal to RCV.NXT+RCV.WND while the receive window is not zero (second row in the table).

This essentially means that the segment will be discarded, other than possibly sending an ACK. No ACK processing or send window update will be done.

What is the justification of this?

Consider this scenario:

1. Host A sends all possible data segments to host B, just exhausting the  receive window of B.
2. Host A shortly also sends an empty segment, e.g. a window update or acknowledgement of received data. This segment has sequence number equal to the right edge of the receive window of host B (RCV.NXT+RCV.WND), since it was set to the latest SND.NXT of host A.
3. The mentioned data packets are lost in the network or delayed, and host B receives the empty segment first.
4. Host B will classify the empty segment as not acceptable, and drop it, ignoring any acknowledgement or window update.

Is there some part that I am not understanding correctly? Is this scenario really possible?

*note*: I ask here instead of on networkengineering.stackexchange.com since  I encountered the issue while implementing a TCP/IP stack and these protocol details seem closer to programming than what is commonly understood as network engineering.

Comment: It doesn't say 'a sequence number equal to RCV.NXT+RCV.WND'. It says 'RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND'.

Comment: @EJP This inequality is false when SEG.SEQ=RCV.NXT+RCV.WND and RCV.WND is nonzero - hence such a segment is deemed non-acceptable. I don't see your point, did I write something false?